# how do you get an Idlingresource to work in Kotlin with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, okhttp, anko

My Espresso Idling Resource is not working - it compiles and runs but no longer waits long enough for the result to be returned from the 'net.

---

1. Start with https://github.com/chiuki/espresso-samples/tree/master/idling-resource-okhttp
2. Convert the main activity to Kotlin - test (which is still in java) still works with OKHttpIdlingResource
3. Convert to anko coroutine call instead of retrofit.enqueue - test no longer works.

Here is the new code for MainActivity in its entirety

```html
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import org.jetbrains.anko.coroutines.experimental.bg

import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        doCallAsync()
    }

    private fun doCallAsync() = async(UI) {

        val user = bg { getUser() }
        val name = user.await().name
        val nameView = findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView

        nameView.text = name;

    }

    private fun getUser(): User {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://api.github.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .client(OkHttpProvider.getOkHttpInstance())
                .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(GitHubService::class.java)


        val response = service.getUser("chiuki").execute().body()

        return response!!

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Convert to anko coroutine call instead of retrofit.enqueue - test no longer works.`

`retrofit.enqueue` uses OkHttp's dispatcher. This is what the "idling-resource-okhttp" recognizes and communicates to the idlingresource manager.

However by using `retrofit.execute` and anko's `bg` you are using a different execution mechanism that the idlingresource manager does not know about, so while it might be executing the application is idle from the view of the manager, thus ending the test.

To fix this you need to register an `IdlingResource` for whatever execution mechanism `bg` uses, so it can recognize when there is something happening on that thread of execution.

Comment: "for whatever execution mechanism bg uses" - this is of course the issue.  And unfortunately we're using Follestad Material Dialog instead of DialogFragment so we can't easily (afaik) check the existence of dialogfragment (eg progress dialog)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an `IdlingResource` to tell Espresso whether the app is currently idle or not (as Kiskae wrote). AFAIK for coroutines there does not exist a central registry that can tell you whether there is a coroutine running.

So you have to keep track of them yourself as suggested in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource.html#example-implementations) by using a `CountingIdlingResource`. Add this convenience `async`-wrapper to your project:

```
public fun <T> asyncRes(
        idlingResource: CountingIdlingResource,
        context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher,
        start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
        parent: Job? = null,
        block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): Deferred<T> = async(context, start, parent) {
    try {
        idlingResource.increment()
        block()
    } finally {
        idlingResource.decrement()
    }
}
```

Add an instance of `CountingIdlingResource` inside your Activity, call `asyncRes` instead of `async` and pass in the `CountingIdlingResource`.

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    // Active coroutine counter
    val idlingResource = CountingIdlingResource("coroutines")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        doCallAsync()
    }

    private fun doCallAsync() = asyncRes(idlingResource, UI) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```